# Web embedding of CDF with dynamic content

Tags: cdf-format

I made a widget that calculates some values as variables are dynamically changed with sliders. I want to embed the cdf here:

http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~majewski/nqr/match

As you can see, this isn't working. I do not know why.  I found something in help files that says dynamic content may be stopping it from working.  Is that what is happening here?

The code for the widget is in plain text here:

http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~majewski/nqr/matching-A-nb

by changing the above URL to

```
.../~majewski/nqr/matching-A{.nb, -nb, .cdf, -cdf, .pdf}
```

...etc you can see the various other files involved.  Sorry, I could only post 2 links here.

You may also find the github repository by navigating to my homepage at `.../~majewski` and finding my repo `https://github.com/Altoidnerd/NMR-Tank-Circuits`

Comment: I'm guessing you are testing it with Google Chrome? In this case it won't work, because the CDF player does not work with Google Chrome. In Chrome it is displaying the default content which you specified by writing `<a href="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/"><img  src="matching-A.cdf"></a>` This code is nonsensical: The image tag displays an image with the URL given in `src`. You CDF is not an image.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Im not seeing any issue.  I get much the same results from your web page (using IE) as I do when pasting your code into a notebook.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it is working. What exact behaviour are you facing?

Comment: Cross posted on [WC](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/418505?p_p_auth=e2YvdGAd).

Comment: @Kuba He has updated the code - could be in response to what I wrote for all we know - and so in Chrome you should now see an image, but not the CDF itself. Whether or not you can see CDFs in Chrome depends on your system, but I think [most people can't](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67540/cdf-plugin-no-longer-launches-in-chrome).