# CDF Player 10.0.2 does not launch

Tags: cdfplayer

I have recently downloaded the new CDF Player 10.0.2.
I export a CDF, and create an HTML page, to host the CDF, using the code provided by Mathematica 10.0.2.

When I open the HTML page in Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit), it asks me to get the CDF Player, which I already have.
Relaunching the browser or restarting the computer have no effect.

The HTML file does launch the Player in Safari Version 8.0.3.

This is related to an [earlier problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67540/cdf-plugin-no-longer-launches-in-chrome), but now occurs with CDF Player 10.0.2.

Any others see this problem, or have advice?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the CDF browser plugin, not the "Wolfram CDF Player" application?

Chrome is now 64-bit application, and since the CDF Player plugin is 32-bit, it will not work. Even if it were made 64-bit, Chrome is planning on disabling these types of plugins (NPAPI) soon.

For the moment, it should work in Safari and Firefox on OSX.

Comment: Yes, I did mean the plug-in. I am probably not aware of all the issues, but I wonder why Wolfram accepts this situation. Here are browser usage stats from a highly trafficked site that I manage: Chrome 48.69%
Firefox 19.01%
Safari 18.84%
Internet Explorer 10.20%. It also seems poor customer/public relations to have cdf enabled web pages display a button saying "get the wolfram cdf player" when in fact that will do them no good.

Comment: This situation renders embedded CDF effectively useless on web sites.