# Sudden CDF file web embedding plug in Failed

Tags: cdf-format, wolfram-player

Until 15 days ago I embed the CDF file on this site and made good use of it.

The inserted source is as follows.

```
<script src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v2.1/cdfplugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var cdf = new cdfplugin();
cdf.setDefaultContent('<a href=http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/ target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.sitename.com/ex.png"></a>');
cdf.embed('http://www.sitename.com/ex.cdf',257,126); 
</script>
```

However, the CDF file embedded in the web page from a few days ago is not a plug-in. I did not modify this web page.

In any case, I tested it at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com and confirmed that the site was plugged in and working properly.

My work environment is Windows 7, 64 bit, Explorer 11, and Mathematica and Wolfram CDF Player 11.1 are installed.

I would like to know why suddenly things that have worked well in the past, such as the above script, have been inserted into a web page.

Comment: Is this the answer? [CDF plugin no longer launches in Chrome](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67540/5478) or http://support.wolfram.com/kb/20057

Comment: Is the cdf plugin now stopped on internet explorer 11 anymore?

Answer (score 2):

CDF is no longer supported in Mathematica, and the plug-in was deprecated because browsers no longer allow NPAPI plugins. You have to host the file on Wolfram Cloud.